# Python assignment of values within an array

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a vector several times and then change one of its elements:

```
from copy import deepcopy

v = [0.5,1.0,2.0]
m = 3 * [deepcopy(v)]
# m = [[0.5,1.0,2.0],[0.5,1.0,2.0],[0.5,1.0,2.0]]
m [0][0] = "Python"
# m = [["Python",1.0,2.0],["Python",1.0,2.0],["Python",1.0,2.0]]
```

as you can see instead of just changing the 0 element form the 0 array, it is changing all the 0 elements.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, except for the last line. The last line is output or part of the code?

Comment: It's the output...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did here was that you made three references to the same thing.

`3 * [deepcopy(v)]` simply made 3 different references to the same list.

You would want to do

```
m = [deepcopy(v) for x in range(3)]
```